Needing to move and rename multiple files 1 at a time was wondering if bat can do this
So I'm currently working on the old "Movies" setup on my hard drive based on a 5 year old video from youtube I watch about 2 years ago and since I'm just getting start again with kodi I need to change a bunch of the info since this never really worked for me before.
So here is what I need to do:
First I took some movies from the "Movies" section of the external hard drive and made a new folder called "Need to Fix" and then inside that folder is a folder for each movie like this: Batman Begins (2005) this would be the name of the folder. And inside should be only 1 folder the .actors folder and that should be it. but nope I was using "media Companion" and there is now 3 folders extrathumbs which will be deleted as well as extrafanart which will also be deleted. Plus I also added a folder to more then half of the main movie folders called Featurettes with a file inside called Trailer.mp4.
Now here is the issue I need to rename each of the Trailer.mp4 file the name of the movie and then have -trailer.mp4 so it should look like this Batman Begins (2005)-trailer.mp4 not just Trailer. And it should be moved from Featurettes to the main folder and then Featurettes should be removed.
So is there a way to move all the .mp4 files to there main movies file and then rename them to match the main movie and include -trailer at the file name.
so basically I would be moving the .mp4 file from G:\Need To Fix\G.I. Joe The Rise of Cobra (2009)\Featurettes to G:\Need To Fix\G.I. Joe The Rise of Cobra (2009)
and then renaming it from Trailers.mp4 to G.I. Joe The Rise of Cobra (2009)-trailer. Is there a way to do this in bulk.
I know of the easiest way to grab the Featurettes folder all I need to do is: left click on need to fix folder on left side of file explorer and then select all with check box and then copy as path and then paste into notepad++ and then start at top of list and do a search and just add Featurettes to the end of each line so I don't need to open each folder to find the actual location of each Featurettes folder. And then just move the files form inside that folder to the main folder. but I don't know how to do this with bat. Is there even a way to do this. I can remove the files easy enough in file explorer once the file has been moved and renamed correctly but I'm having issues with renaming on "Bulk Renamer Utility" I don't know how to rename things in bulk with that program since each Trailer file is inside a different folder and each needs a different name.
So is there a way to do this with bat. I need to rename the files and move the files. I think moving them first would be best and then just rename them based on the folder name and include -trailer before the .mp4.
I have been using bulk renamer utility and have been working with notepad++ to try and make the work a bit easier but it still takes a long time to get the job done.
 @ECHO ON

 SET MoveToDir=G:\Need To Fix\Gladiator (2000)
 SET MoveToDir=G:\Need To Fix\Godzilla (1998)
 SET MoveToDir=G:\Need To Fix\Godzilla (2014)
 SET MoveToDir=G:\Need To Fix\Godzilla King of the Monsters (2019)
 SET MoveToDir=G:\Need To Fix\Godzilla vs. Kong (2021)
 SET MoveToDir=G:\Need To Fix\Good Will Hunting (1997)
 SET MoveFromDir=G:\Need To Fix\Gladiator (2000)\Featurettes
 SET MoveFromDir=G:\Need To Fix\Godzilla (1998)\Featurettes
 SET MoveFromDir=G:\Need To Fix\Godzilla (2014)\Featurettes
 SET MoveFromDir=G:\Need To Fix\Godzilla King of the Monsters                           (2019)\Featurettes
SET MoveFromDir=G:\Need To Fix\Godzilla vs. Kong (2021)\Featurettes
SET MoveFromDir=G:\Need To Fix\Good Will Hunting (1997)\Featurettes

:: Move the folders from the move directory to the move to     directory
FOR /D %%A IN ("%MoveFromDir%\*") DO MOVE /Y "%%~A" "%MoveToDir%"

:: Move any remaining files (or folders) from the move directory to the move to directory
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN ('DIR /S /B "%MoveFromDir%\*.*"') DO MOVE /Y "%%~A" "%MoveToDir%\"
GOTO EOF

This is how I tried to do it I think I did some thing wrong though and I named it move mp4 files.bat and placed it inside the Need to Fix folder and then I double clicked it but it didn't move any files from the folders. Is there a way to fix this and move all mp4 files at once with this bat file.

I have tried using the tip from the comment at this link and it did not work I had added multiple file locations and maybe that is why it didn't work I'm not sure.[Link]https://superuser.com/questions/1115231/batch-move-a-folders-content-up-one-level it was "Batch move a folder's content up one level"

Well the first thing I have to point out is that you have defined tha variable named MoveToDir with only a single value string of G:\Need To Fix\Good Will Hunting (1997), and one named MoveFromDir with the value of G:\Need To Fix\Good Will Hunting (1997)\Featurettes, because each time you have overwritten the previous values with another! I have no idea why anyone would be crazy enough to have a directory name containing a sequence of twenty seven spaces either!

Its on a hard drive and there for kodi each movie needs to be in its own folder and each folder needs to be named the same thing as the movie. So for example on the hard drive I have a folder called "Movies" and each folder inside if that has a folder titled the same thing as each movie. and all the movie stuff like cover art and trailer gets stored inside each folder. So Batman Begins (2005) is the name of a folder and there is 2 mp4 files in side there with some images as well as a nfo file. So some folders have even more spaces it all depends on the name of the movie.

How do I fix the code so I can move multiple files at the same time. Or is there another code I should be using. I'm not to good with this sort of stuff that's why I'm asking.

Perhaps you could utilize the RoboCopy utility. Open a Command prompt window, type %SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe /? and press the [ENTER] key to find out its available options. You should also take a look at the output from Dir /?,  For /?, and Set /?, which are almost certainly going to come in useful to you.

Let us assume the folder G:\Need To Fix contains following folders and files before execution of the batch file:

Gladiator (2000)

.actors

Actors.txt


extrafanart

fanart1.png
fanart2.png


extrathumbs

thumbnail.png


Featurettes

trailer.mp4
cover.png




Godzilla (1998)

.actors

Actors.txt


extrafanart

fanart.jpeg


extrathumbs

thumbnail.png


Featurettes

trailer.mp4





No folder has the hidden attribute set. No file has the hidden or read-only attribute set.
The wanted folder structure and files should be after batch file execution:

Gladiator (2000)

.actors

Actors.txt


Gladiator (2000)-trailer.mp4
Gladiator (2000)-cover.png


Godzilla (1998)

.actors

Actors.txt


Godzilla (1998)-trailer.mp4



This can be achieved with following batch file:
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "ErrorOccurred="
if exist "G:\Need To Fix\" %SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe -H -R "G:\Need To Fix\*" /D /S
for /D %%I in ("G:\Need To Fix\*") do (
    echo Processing folder: "%%~nxI"
    if exist "%%I\extrafanart\" rd /Q /S "%%I\extrafanart" || set "ErrorOccurred=1"
    if exist "%%I\extrathumbs\" rd /Q /S "%%I\extrathumbs" || set "ErrorOccurred=1"
    if exist "%%I\Featurettes\" (
        for %%J in ("%%I\Featurettes\*") do move /Y "%%J" "%%I\%%~nxI-%%~nxJ" 1>nul || set "ErrorOccurred=1"
        rd "%%I\Featurettes" || set "ErrorOccurred=1"
    )
)
if defined ErrorOccurred pause
endlocal

There is the command pause executed at the end if one of the files could not be moved successfully or one of the directories could not be removed from file system. Look in this case on the movie folder on which processing an error was output because of one of the directories to remove is the current working directory of a running process or one of the files to delete or move is currently opened by a running application.
To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

attrib /?
echo /?
endlocal /?
for /?
if /?
move /?
pause /?
rd /?
set /?
setlocal /?

See also:

Microsoft documentation about Using command redirection operators for an explanation of the redirection 1>nul.
Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file for an explanation of the conditional command operator ||.

